# iOS 13 track user location when app is killed

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I want to track user location even when app is killed by the user. I have tried below code but not working when an app is closed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
         self.checkUsersLocationServicesAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }


extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        for location in locations {

            let objr = ["lat": "\(location.coordinate.latitude)",
                "logn": "\(location.coordinate.longitude)",
                "date": self.getCurrentDateAndTime()]
            self.saveToCoreDataAndFetchBack(objr as NSDictionary)
            //self.TriggerNotification()
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: `I want to track user location even when app is killed by the user.` for what reason?

Comment: location track between frequent intervals. To know whether the employee is at work location or not.

Comment: You can implement things like visit tracking or geofencing for this (Apple has docs for this). Users kill apps for a reason, they don't want you to continuously track their location.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want your location manager object living in a view controller. You will, need to use a suitable location mode, such as significant location change and write the appropriate code in `didFinishLaunching` to handle a relaunch for location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options to track user location when app is killed:

1 -> **Region Monitoring aka geofencing**: You will setup a region to be monitored & when user enter or leave that region, the iOS system will wake up your app & notify you in application delegate about location update.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/monitoring_the_user_s_proximity_to_geographic_regions

2-> **Significant-Change location service**: In this case, iOS system will wake up your app only when user's location is significantly changed. The value is around 500 meters.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service

**Note**: For both of these features to work, you will need '**Always**' location permission from user.

Decided which method is suitable for you & then dive into the its documentation.

Comment: Fahad Masood thank you for your solution, I can able to get the location using both the scenarios. But how to send that location to the server? Is this possible to call API when the app is killed

Comment: I have not tried that, but I am confident that this can be done. The system does wake up your app in this case, so you may try to call API in app delegate and see if it works